# Расшифровка файла данных

Tags: декомпиляция

Есть стороння программа. Есть файл с данными стороней программы (порядка 50-100 мб), в нем содержиться куча инфы, в том числе геометрическая (список точек, линий и тд). Мне необходимо получить **только** геометрию.

Интересуют возможные методы, в какое направление копать.

Comment: Вариант один: копать в сторону дизассемблера и отладчика. 

Вам придется понять как программа работает с этими данными. Тогда станет понятен их формат в файле. 

Работа кропотливая, небыстрая, занудная (хотя, кому как...) и часто неблагодарная.

--

Другой вариант: "подружиться" с разработчиками и убедить их поделиться своими знаниями. Но этот путь требует специфической подготовки (вне тем данного форума).

Comment: Первый вариант думал, но мне так кажется что займет это вечность) 2й вариант- не вариант) А какие методы\способы применить для анализа файла данных?

Comment: Записываете этой программой в новый файл известную геометрию, **делаете предположения о возможном формате** (например, что 3-D точка это 3 числа в формате float, которые лежат в файле рядом) и ищете похожие места в файле. 

Смотрите их смещения. Ищете похожие смещения (числа в файле). Смотрите на числа где-то перед ними. 

Думаете, думаете....

Повторяете все с начала.

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не могу создавать файлы, открыть могу, но без точных данных о геометрии (вижу результат в растре).